# Angular: select access selected label

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
<form name="myForm"
  <select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="...">
</form>
```

which outputs:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  ...
</select>
```

In my controller, I can access the selected `value` through `$scope.myModal`, but can I access the `First` label? Maybe through `$scope.myForm`?

I'd like to avoid having to store all options in a `$scope` variable, and having to filter back again in the controller...

Comment: Could you not access it through the same collection that you used in `ng-options` to build the `<select>` in the first place?

Comment: The list of your option isn't set in `ng-options`? If so, you have already access to these data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the object as the value, on ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="it.name for it in list"></select>

<p>Value selected (id): {{ selected.id }}</p>
<p>Label selected: {{ selected.name }}</p>
```

I made an example, take a look: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/venoni/edit?html,js,output)